# Don't Render always on top Unity world space canvas UI

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-ui

I have a **World Space Canvas** where I have a **text** object which is always rendering on top. I checked that it has `UI/Default` Shader attach. Is there any way available to not render always on top, the 3d UI text.? Any built-in or custom shader available to restrict it? I tried diffuse shader but now the text is not readable. I have also tried a shader from [**another post at gamedev**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/why-is-my-textmesh-always-on-top?rq=1) but the problem is still persist.

Comment: have you tried editing the sortingOrder of the Canvas (in inspector or from code) ?

Comment: No, I didn't tried it yet. I should need to read it first

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking? If you're using a world space canvas then your UI will already be rendered like any other world space object, so If you want it to render behind/in front of some other gameobject you could just move it further/closer to the camera.

Comment: @OmarGuendeli said right I think you should try it [same question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155111/ui-and-line-renderer-layer-order-when-using-screen-space-camera/155155#155155)

Comment: @SamJudge Yeah you are right, i have world space canvas but actually its text is always rendering on top that i want to restrict.